# Use result of upper query in union clause in lower query

Tags: oracle, union

I am using union operator to combine results of 2 queries. Now I want to use the result of first query in second query so that I can exclude some records from second query.

E.g.

```
select <some_columns> from tableA Union select <same_columns> from tableA where <one_column_val> != <some_val_from_first_query>
```

Below is my query

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, c.*
  FROM tableA a,
       tableB b,
       tableC c
    where b.field_1 = c.field_1
    and a.field_2 = c.field_2
union
SELECT a.*, b.*, c.*
  FROM tableA a,
       tableB b,
       tableC c
    where b.field_1 = c.field_1
    and a.field_3=c.field_3
    and a.field_2 <> {a.field_2 from upper query}
```

Please suggest the required alteration.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Each select in a SQL union has no knowledge of the others. So, you simply have to explicitly write out the entire query again, in your case either as a NOT EXISTS or a NOT IN. As an example, you can see the entire query copied as a derived table in a NOT EXISTS clause:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, c.*
  FROM tableA a,
       tableB b,
       tableC c
    where b.field_1 = c.field_1
    and a.field_2 = c.field_2
union
SELECT a.*, b.*, c.*
  FROM tableA a,
       tableB b,
       tableC c
    where b.field_1 = c.field_1
    and a.field_3=c.field_3
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from (
            SELECT a.*, b.*, c.*
            FROM tableA a,
                tableB b,
                tableC c
            where b.field_1 = c.field_1
            and a.field_2 = c.field_2
        ) x
        where a.field_2 = x.field_2
    )
```

If your RDBMS supports CTEs you can abstract the query into a CTE and not repeat yourself. Note you should probably also be using JOIN syntax if your RDBMS supports it, and you may have column name collisions with the `*` selector that you'll have to resolve.